# Naive turning point question

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In our cal class, we are learning how to use derivatives and critical points to sketch graphs. We were recently introduced to the idea of concavity.

All I would like to know is that is it possible to have a point on a continuous function such that

```
                dy/dx=0 at x=c
                and 
                for x<c
                dy/dx >0 and
                the double derivative>0 
                (i.e.the function is increasing and concave up before c)
```

The reason I ask is I am having a hard time imagining how the derivative at c could exist if as I approach c from the left the slopes get larger and then all of a sudden go to zero. I even tried drawing a graph of dy/dx against x and this just convinced me more that such a point can never exist.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, as long as the first and second derivatives exist.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x) > 0$ for all $a < x < b$, then the function $f(x)$ is increasing on the interval $(a,b)$. That is, if $u,v \in (a,b)$ and $u < v$, then $f(u) < f(v)$. When the derivative is positive, the function values go up as you move to the right. They cannot go down.

Now, you were talking about the second derivative, not the first. But actually, that same principle is all it takes to show this. If $f''(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$, then it is the first derivative of the function $f'(x)$. So if $f''(x) > 0$ everywhere on $(a,b)$ implies that $f'(x)$ is increasing.

In your case, you have on some interval $(a,c)$ that $f'(x) > 0$, and that $f''(x) > 0$. Because of that second condition, $f'(x)$ is increasing. So if I choose some $p \in (a,c)$, and let $m = f'(p)$. Then for every $x > p, f'(x) > f'(p) = m$.

By the limit comparison theorem, $\lim_{x\to c-} f'(x) \ge \lim_{x\to c-} m = m > 0$. So if $f'(x)$ is continuous at $c$, we must also have $f'(c) \ge m$. (And if the second derivative $f''(c)$ exists, then $f'(x)$ must be continuous at $c$.)